# what if html_escape would stop escaping '&'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there any danger if the rails html_escape function would stop escaping '&'? I tested a few cases and it doesn't seem to create any problems. Can you give me a contrary an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put an unescaped "&" into an HTML attribute, it would make your page invalid. For example:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/?Product=1949&View=1">Link</a>
```

The page is now invalid as the & indicates an entity. This is true for any usage of an & on a page (for example, view source and *hopefully* you'll notice that Stack Overflow escapes the & signs in this post!)

The following would make the above example valid:

```
<a href="http://yoursite.com/?Product=1949&amp;View=1">Link</a>
```

## Additional Note

`&` characters *do* need to be escaped in URLs if you want to validate your markup against the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org). Example:

```
Line 9, Column 38: & did not start a character reference. 
(& probably should have been escaped as &amp;.)

    <a href="/Example.html?id=987&type=5">Example</a>
```

Comment: `&` does not need to be escaped within quotes.

Comment: @Chloe - you *could* check each one to see whether it is ambiguous or not, but escaping all ampersands is safer. An ampersand can still be ambiguous - even inside of quotes. See http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-ambiguous-ampersand

Answer (score 0):

change an url with adding some argument